# Does IdHttpServer OnCommandGet event runs inside a thread?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, indy

Does the `idHttpServer` `OnCommandGet` run inside a thread? I guess Indy creates a thread and call this event inside it, but I am not really sure about it.

It Indy does that, is it ok to set a `threadvar` inside this event and read this var from the methods my `OnCommandGet` calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it runs in a thread that Indy creates and manages. You can verify this by calling [`GetCurrentThreadID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683183.aspx) and comparing the result to the global [`MainThreadID`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.MainThreadID) variable.

Although you *can* use threadvars, consider just passing those values as simple *parameters* to the functions you call instead. Then you don't have all the downsides of global variables.

Comment: Yeah, i know i should do that. This is only for educational purposes. I am trying to understand a legacy code. Thanks for helping.